# mongoexport not exporting all possible data

Tags: mongodb, export

I have a collection with documents similar to the following:

```
{
 _id: 'p_123456',
 id: 123456,
 kind: 'person'
 data: [...]
}
```

id field can contain either positive or negative integers.
This collection contains close to 100 million documents and I have a python script which I use in order to process the data from the collection.

I'm trying to export all the data, but into 8 different processes using the $mod operator in the following way:
    `mongoexport -u user -p password -d db -c collection --query "{\$and:[{kind:'person'},{id:{\$mod:[8,\$i]}}]}" | python process.py` - where $i is a number between 0 - 7.

For some reason I've noticed that when I use this method with 8 processes not all the data is being exported just 65 million out of 87 million for this specific kind.

If I run a single mongoexport process with the query `{kind:'person'}` only, all 87 million documents are being exported.

Is it possible that running 8 different proccesses with `$mod:[8,0]` to `$mod:[8,7]` isn't enough in order to export all the data? what am I missing here?

**EDIT 1:**
Following AdamC suggestion, I ran the following map reduce:

```
var map = function() {
  if (this.kind == 'person'){
      var key = this.id % 8
      if (key < 0){
          key = key * (-1)
      }
      emit( key, 1 );
  }
};


var reduce = function( key, values ) {    
  return Array.sum(values);
}
```

The results returned as expected ~87 million records:

```
> db.map_reduce_modulus.find()
{ "_id" : 0, "value" : 10886482 }
{ "_id" : 1, "value" : 10878131 }
{ "_id" : 2, "value" : 10881552 }
{ "_id" : 3, "value" : 10882586 }
{ "_id" : 4, "value" : 10886060 }
{ "_id" : 5, "value" : 10882565 }
{ "_id" : 6, "value" : 10886171 }
{ "_id" : 7, "value" : 10883563 }
```

Therefor I don't think this is a type issue

Thanks for advance

Comment: Whats the output if you run the query with .count() in mongo?

Comment: 87107467 results

Comment: mapReduce uses JavaScript, so your assertion here is incorrect. e.g `var string = "10"; string % 8` would return a numeric `2` even though the data is a string. That's just how JavaScript works. `$type` actually looks at the BSON type, which is a very different assertion.

Answer (score 1):

I can only speculate without having access to the data, but I suspect that you have non-numeric data in the `id` field.  Try using the [`$type` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) to verify that some of the fields have not been passed in as strings or similar and that all the fields are homogeneous in terms of type.

Comment: I've added more information to the body of the question. is it possible that mongoexport changes the type of fields?

Comment: Hi,
I even went ahead and checked the $type, even though I suspect it's not the issue:
db.my_collection.find({$and: [{kind: 'person'},{id:{$type: 16}}]}).count():

87071995

Comment: @MenyIssakov I can try to reproduce, but would need to know what indexes you have on that collection - can you add that information to the question?  Can you also comment on the lower/upper bound for the integer in the id field?